# Subtract float from list

Tags: python, list, replace

I trying to subtract float from list , my problem its to replace him with the new number without changing index. something like replace?

```
a = [1, 2.2, 3]
b = -1

#I trying to do something like that:
                                     #a.replace(a[1] + b)

#my final result need to be
a = [1, 1.2, 3]
```

Comment: `a[1] = a[1] - b`

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the `replace()` function on lists, they are to be used on strings. Instead, use the index of the list value you want to change and assign it to a certain value:

```
a = [1, 2.2, 3]
b = -1

a[1] += b
a[1] = round(a[1], 1) # Optional
print(a)
```

`a[1] += b`
is equivalent to `a[1] = a[1] + b`, which is just getting `2.2` and subtracting  `1` from it. Then we round the number to the nearest tenth to get the desired output.

Comment: The `round` shouldn't be necessary, by the rules of IEEE arithmetic the result should already be as close to correct as it can be.